# how to produce image with semanticSegmentationSkyMatteImage information on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, semantic-segmentation

I'm trying to create a sky mask on pictures taken from my iPhone.
I've seen in the documentation that CoreImage support semantic segmentation for Sky among other type for person (skin, hair etc...)

For now, I didn't found the proper workflow to use it.

First, I watched https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/225/

I understood that images must be captured with the segmentation with this kind of code:

```
photoSettings.enabledSemanticSegmentationMatteTypes = self.photoOutput.availableSemanticSegmentationMatteTypes
photoSettings.embedsSemanticSegmentationMattesInPhoto = true
```

I capture the image on my iPhone, save it as HEIC format then later, I try to load the matte like that :

```
let skyMatte = CIImage(contentsOf: imageURL, options: [.auxiliarySemanticSegmentationSkyMatte: true])
```

Unfortunately, `self.photoOutput.availableSemanticSegmentationMatteTypes` always give me a list of types for person only and never a types Sky.

Anyway, the AVSemanticSegmentationMatte.MatteType is just [Hair, Skin, Teeth, Glasses] ... No Sky !!!

So, How am I supposed to use semanticSegmentationSkyMatteImage ?!?
Is there any simple workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

So unfortunately, the answer is to use private libraries.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).